# firebase не работает на другом устройстве

Tags: firebase

На другом устройстве не подключается конфиг скорее всего, а ошибку выдает, что нет доступа к catalogs, это те данные, которые лежат в database

```
{
"rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    "users": {
        "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'avatar'])",
                "name":{
            ".validate": "newData.val().length > 0"
            },
                "avatar":{
                    ".validate": "newData.val().length > 0"
            }
       }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно устройства которое выдает ошибку не поддерживает firebase, попробуйте использовать более новое устройства для проверки